# Is "in fact" a typical phrase to introduce a quick proof of a claim in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

One of my mathematics professors, a German native, frequently makes small claims in his lecture notes, which he then justifies in the following sentence, which always begins "In fact, ...".

I was wondering if this is a typical construction in mathematics, as it seems at odds with normal usage of "in fact" in English (i.e., usually to introduce a similar, but stronger point).

I have the impression that this is a mistranslation of the German phrase "*in der Tat*", which (I believe) *is* used for this purpose in German mathematics. But I could be wrong.

Example:

> The scalar product is Lipschitz on each ball of $X^2$ and thus continuous from $X^2$ to $\mathbb{F}$. In fact, Cauchy-Schwarz yields ... 
>   *[inequality demonstrating Lipschitz].*

Comment: In my experience, it is usually used to emphasise a point by stating something stronger which implies the result. Example: "$f$ is continuous. In fact, $f$ is differentiable...."

Comment: I don't know the German. The usage you quote isn't wrong, but it's a little misleading. @Joppy 's comment is what I was about to write.

Comment: Instead of "in der Tat" I assume he actually means "und zwar" or "Und tatsächlich" what could be translated into english as "Indeed" … so it's more like "The scalar product is Lipschitz on each ball of $X^2$ and thus continuous from $X^2$ to $\mathbb{F}$. Indeed, Cauchy-Schwarz yields ..."

Answer (score 0):

*Pulling down @Joppy's comment from above.*

---

In my experience, it is usually used to emphasise a point by stating something stronger which implies the result. Example: "$f$ is continuous. In fact, $f$ is differentiable...."